# OS X MRTG Binary into APP?

Tags: macos, mrtg

is there an easy way to somehow pull stats from my Apple TimeCapsule (maybe through snmp) on OS X?

I mean I know "hard" way would be installing of MRTG on my mac and configure it, then showing through my web server, but is there a something like PRTG for Windows? but for MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airport Extreme (and I assume TimeCapsule as well) supports SNMP. You can turn it on in the Advanced / Logging & Statistics panel.

For an easy way to view the SNMP traffic, without having to install MRTG or [NRG](http://homepage.mac.com/duling/halfdozen/NRG-Howto-p1.html), there's a Dashboard widget called [iEyeNet](http://www.digitician.com.au/iEyeNet/index.html).

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for... All I gotta figure out what's using 6mbps on my Mac now..